# Include glossary in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries

I am using `\usepackage{glossaries}`. How do you include it in `\tableofcontents`? The following does not do the trick:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{mwe}{MWE}{Minimum Working Example}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\printglossaries

\clearpage

\chapter{Foo}
This is the call to the \Gls{mwe}

\end{document}
```

This is my output:

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the `toc` package option or add `\glstoctrue` to your preamble. See section 2.2 of the manual for details.

By default, glossaries will appear as chapters if the document class features the `\chapter` command and as sections otherwise. You can change the default behavior using the `section` key-value-option; e.g.,

```
\usepackage[toc,section=section]{glossaries}
```

will result in section-like glossaries for the `book` and `report` class.

Comment: This option adds to toc as a chapter, how can i have it added as a section, have tried \let\chapter=\section, but doesn't seem to do the trick, my guess is that \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{...} is being called, so needs to be patched instead to \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{...}, but how?

Comment: @ADP See updated answer.

Comment: perfect. Cheers.