# Glossaries showing in appendix and in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries, acronyms

Glossary or Acronyms not showing as section headers in the appendix, and as such not on the table of contents.

I'd like it the table of contents and appendices to look like this.

```
Contents
1 Section Heading
A Appendix Heading
B Glossary
C Acronyms
```

Below is a short example of what I am doing.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in,headheight=110pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}
\newglossaryentry{api}
{
    name={API},
    plural={APIs},
    description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software program that implements that API},
    first={Application Programming Interface (API)},
    long={Application Programming Interface}
}

\title{TOC Example}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\startcontents[mainsection]
\section{Section Heading}
\lipsum[1]
\gls{cd}
\gls{api}
\stopcontents[mainsection]

\appendix
\startcontents[appendices]
\section*{Appendices}
\section{Appendix Heading}
\lipsum[1]
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to use the `toc` package option to add the glossaries to the table of contents: `\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}`

Comment: Related: [Include glossary in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98196/include-glossary-in-table-of-contents)

Comment: I think @NicolaTalbot has a better idea of how to solve this, so I will defer to him on this.

Comment: If adding the `toc` package option provides a solution then this question can be closed as a duplicate of the one I linked to above. (I've got a gold `glossaries` badge which means if I vote to close this as a duplicate it will instantly be closed, so I'd rather get confirmation before doing that.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I did try that and whilst you are correct in that it does add the glossaries to the table of contents it doesn't add them with a number which was what I was after.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I've answered my own question, hope this is enough to not close the question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the numbering in your desired output, otherwise I would've recommended `numberedsection` instead of `toc`. I agree it's not a duplicate to the question I linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since worked out what I was wanting to do and the example code below works.

The command `\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{\section{#1}}` rewrites the headings so that they are sections, which then get added to the table of contents and with a number, hope this helps someone!

```
    \documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in,headheight=110pt]{geometry}
    \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{titletoc}

    % Make glossaries
    \makeglossaries
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{\section{#1}}

    \newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}
    \newglossaryentry{api}
    {
        name={API},
        plural={APIs},
        description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software program that implements that API},
        first={Application Programming Interface (API)},
        long={Application Programming Interface}
    }

    \title{TOC Example}

    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    % Start mainsection content to be included in table of contents
    \startcontents[mainsection]

    \section{Section Heading}
    \gls{api}

    % End mainsection content to be included in table of contents
    \stopcontents[mainsection]

    \clearpage

    \appendix

    % Start appendices content to be included in table of contents
    \startcontents[appendices]
    \section*{Appendices}

    \section{Appendix Heading}
    \lipsum[1]

    \printglossaries

    \end{document}
```

Comment: If you want numbered sections, it's simpler just to use the `numberedsection` package option. Your definition of `\glossarysection` uses the `toctitle` setting for both the header and table of contents. This may be okay for your particular use, but it's not a general purpose solution.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I just tried that and I can't seem to tell the difference between them, so I am using your simpler suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are simply labeling the `\section{}`s incorrectly. If you label them with what you want, then you get the TOC that you desire.

```
    \documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in,headheight=110pt]{geometry}
    \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{titletoc}

    % Make glossaries
    \makeglossaries
    \newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}
    \newglossaryentry{api}
    {
        name={API},
        plural={APIs},
        description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software program that implements that API},
        first={Application Programming Interface (API)},
        long={Application Programming Interface}
    }

    \title{TOC Example}

    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    % Start mainsection content to be included in table of contents
    \startcontents[mainsection]
    %\printcontents[mainsection]{l}{1}{\section*{Main Sections}\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}

    \section{Section Heading}
    \lipsum[1]

    % End mainsection content to be included in table of contents
    \stopcontents[mainsection]

    \clearpage

    \appendix

    % Start appendices content to be included in table of contents
    \startcontents[appendices]
    \section*{Appendices}

    \section{Appendix Heading}
    \lipsum[1]

    \section{Glossary}
    \lipsum[1]

    \section{Acronyms}
    \lipsum[1]

    \printglossaries

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add some explanation **why** this is a solution, please?

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I don't think you understood my question, the \printglossaries prints out the headers for the Acronyms and the Glossaries so with your code I get duplicate headers, one from your section, and then another from the \printglossaries.

So the example output you gave is what appears on the table of contents, but the headers are duplicated in the appendix itself.

Comment: @AeroMaxx You're right, I thought it was just a TOC issue, based on your initial figure. Will work on the other part.